# Why is it necessary to explicitly cast a non union typed variable to use it where a union type is expected?

Tags: jquery, typescript, union-types

If I have the following TypeScript:

```js
interface SummaryTileDictionary { [ tileId: string ]: JQuery<HTMLElement>; }

class SummaryTileCount {
    tileId: string;
    tileCount: number;

    constructor(tileId: string, tileCount: number) {
        this.tileId = tileId;
        this.tileCount = tileCount;
    }

    updateCount(newCount: number): void {
        this.tileCount = newCount;
        tiles[this.tileId].val(newCount);
    };
}

let tiles: SummaryTileDictionary = {};
let tileCounts: SummaryTileCount[] = [];

tiles["tile-id"] = $("#tile-id");
const tileObject: JQuery<HTMLElement> = $("#" + "tile-id".replace(
    /^([a-z])|-([a-z])/g, _ => _.slice(_.length - 1).toUpperCase()));
myTileCounts.push(new SummaryTileCount(item.id, tileObject.val()));
```

I get the following error from `tsc`:

```
Argument of type 'string | number | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Why does `tsc` infer that the value passed back from `.val()` is a string, if it's been defined as being of type `string | number | string[]`?

At the very least I feel as though the error message should be a little clearer about what's going on here...the way it's currently worded, it seems to a noob like me that `string` satisfies the condition `string | number | string[]`...

Anyway I know I can explicitly cast the `.val()` call's result to a number, but why should I have to? Why is TS not smart enough to do this for me?

*NB: Although this question is tagged as relating to jQuery, it doesn't necessarily...I've seen this type of error far too many times for my liking and would love a general explanation as to why it happens*.

Comment: I think you might not have shared the right code (or not enough of it) because i don't see how those lines could cause that error. `let foo?: number = null;` isn't even syntactically correct, but if i assume it should be `let foo: number | null = null`, there is an error, but it's basically the opposite of the error you're seeing. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAEjgMyhEcDkArAjgVwFMoBPTAbgChKAbQ+ZCCALjgDt8QAjYuAH3b4aNOAF5BwqpQQAKAEQBiECQC0hOiEJsYcgJQA6AG4BDGjMYRd5IA)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I greatly reduced the code to try to illustrate my point as succinctly as possible.  I thought you could use a ? to make a variable nullable, but apparently not (I'll definitely take your word on this over my own) so I'll paste the actual code in 5 mins or so :-)

Comment: Does the question depend on JQuery? If so you might want to tag it as such. If not, could you [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that doesn't depend on undeclared/undefined/third-party types or values? Ideally others could take your code, paste it into their IDEs, and get to work on your issue immediately, without spending times on problems you don't have (like unresolved names... or typos like `myTileCounts`).

Comment: @jcalz: My question is about this type of error coming up in general, as I see it **a lot** and assume the explanation/solution would be applicable in any given scenario. But yes, the example that I *currently* have depends on jQuery, so I'll tag as such :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does tsc infer that the value passed back from .val() is a string, if it's been defined as being of type string | number | string[]?

It's not inferring that the value is actually a `string`. It's just stepping through the possible values and noticing that in the case where it's a `string`, problems ensue.

Typescript checks each member of the union to figure out if your code will work. If you're passing in a `number`, then that works fine, so no error for that case. But if you're passing in a `string` then that's not going to work, because `SummaryTileCount` requires a `number`.

So because of the mismatch for the `string` case, typescript shows the second line of the error, saying that `string` (the thing that might be passed in) is not assignable to `number` (the thing that `SummaryTileCount` asked for). This in turn means that the full type `string | number | string[]` is not assignable to `number`, which it shows as the first line of the error.

(`string[]` would cause a similar error, but for brevity typescript just shows the first error it finds.)

> Anyway I know I can explicitly cast the .val() call's result to a number, but why should I have to? Why is TS not smart enough to do this for me?

Typescript is doing its job and pointing out that the types say this is not safe to do. If you want to use a type assertion, you can, but you should only do that if you have some extra knowledge that's not represented in the types.

```
new SummaryTileCount(item.id, tileObject.val() as number)
```

Keep in mind that a type assertion does not change what the value actually is at runtime, it just tells typescript at compile time "Trust me, i know what i'm doing, so don't check the types here". So if you do a type assertion when it's not correct, typescript won't be able to warn you about it.

Instead of a type assertion, the safe way would be to add code which checks to make sure it's actually a number. For example:

```
const val = tileObject.val()
if (typeof val === 'number') {
  myTileCounts.push(new SummaryTileCount(item.id, val));
} else {
  // Insert logic to handle this case
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the thorough explanation, it's exactly what I was hoping for. I also appreciate the tip re: not relying too much on type assertion, I'll keep it in mind for the future ;-)